# Python toe find the row index

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the 2 inputs, namely a numpy
array (representing a matrix H) and a list (row). Both the matrix (H) and
list (row) only contain integer values.
The function must return the row index (of the matrix H) where the row
values are equal to the list values.
If there is no row in the matrix H that is equal to the list (row) then the
function find row must return -9.
Example 1: if the matrix (H) is equal to:

```
([2,7],
[1,4],
[2,3],
[6,4],
[9,2])
```

and the list (row) is equal to [1, 4], then the function find row should return
the row index 1.
Example 2: if the matrix (H) is equal to:

```
([2, 7, 3],
[1, 4, 1],
[2, 3, 5],
[6, 4, 0],
[9, 2, 2])
```

and the list (row) is equal to [6, 0, 4], then the function find row should
return -9.
Note: the order of values in the row must also be the same as the order
of values in the list. You may assume that the length of the list (row) will
always be equal to the number of columns of the matrix H.

Comment: "cant figure it out" -- because you didn't study. Ask specific doubt *not*  complete solution.

Comment: your lots of help your probably a teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method to check if a row is equal to a list:

```
#only for testing
a = ([2,7],[1,4],[2,3],[6,4],[9,2])
b = [1,4]

def findindex(matrix, row):
    for index in range(0,len(matrix)):
        if matrix[index] == row:
            return index    
    return -9

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(findindex(a, b))
```

Comment: thanx you a life saver